# Looking for simple rss feed reader

Tags: php, rss, rss-reader

Could you recommend a good php rss feed reader class?

I have been doing reasearch for a few hours and managed to waste my time with a few badly built rss feed reading classes. Now I am out of patience

Im sure one of the good people on SO knows of a simple rss feed reader class that I can use

I am using smarty templates and would like to read this feed http://www.greenpeace.org/usa/Templates/Planet3/Handlers/RssHandler.ashx?type=blog&blogid=7156&epslanguage=en-US]

**Edit:** Something very strange is happening. I have set up simplepie and run the demo page at /demo/index.php. It shows other feeds but won't show the uri that I am passing to it. What's even stranger is that that uri does work on the demo page of the simplepie site. I dont get any error messages or anything, just no results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [SimplePie](http://simplepie.org/); it's easy to use, supports caching to minimise bandwidth wastage, etc.

Comment: Hi, I have been trying to get simplepie to work with no success. I think it is an issue with my uri not simple pie. Does this uri look right to you?<br />http://www.greenpeace.org/usa/Templates/Planet3/Handlers/RssHandler.ashx?type=blog&blogid=7156&epslanguage=en-US

Comment: Hi Andrew, yes, that looks right to me; what error are you getting?

Comment: That's the thing Im not getting any error message at all. When I open the uri in my borwser, all the content is there.

Comment: Perhaps if you update with the code you're working on we can help more easily.

Comment: Furthermore, when I use that uri on their site on the demo page it does work. @El Yobo I just ran their demo file that is included with the download with the addition of $feed->set_cache_location($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/cache'); to fix the cache error

Answer (score 0):

Here is a client side solution (jQuery).

http://blog.bobcravens.com/2010/05/build-an-rss-feed-reader-with-jquery-and-jgfeed/

Hope this gets you started.

Bob

Comment: Haven't yet found a good reason to use jQuery but thanks for the info

Answer (score 0):

I like [Magpie RSS](http://magpierss.sourceforge.net/) for a PHP solution.